# Quarkus Building a Native Executable NoSuchFileException: /project

Tags: quarkus

I followed the steps from [build quarkus native executable](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image-guide.html).

1.Bootstrapping the project:

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.11.0:create \
-DprojectGroupId=org.acme \
-DprojectArtifactId=getting-started \
-DclassName="org.acme.quickstart.GreetingResource" \
-Dpath="/hello"
```

2.Use docker in minishift

```
minishift start
eval $(minishift docker-env)
```

3.Generate package:

```
mvn package -Pnative -Dnative-image.docker-build=true
```

failed with the error trace below:

```
[INFO] [io.quarkus.creator.phase.nativeimage.NativeImagePhase] docker run -v /Users/.../quarkus/getting-started/target:/project:z --rm swd847/centos-graal-native-image-rc12 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -jar getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -J-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1 -H:+PrintAnalysisCallTree -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:-SpawnIsolates -H:-JNI --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace
Error: Invalid Path entry getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /project/getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
```

As requested, the tree output is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Could you check without the Minishift step? I suspect it has something to do with it as everything else looks like a standard getting started project.

Comment: I can't really tell from the tree, there is a lot of output. Could you please also add an the output of `ls -l`? Thanks

Comment: @geoand, pls see below, thanks


    `$ ls -l`


    `total 8`


    `-rw-r--r--   1 buhion  staff  3704 Mar 16 10:50 pom.xml`


    `drwxr-xr-x   4 buhion  staff   128 Mar 16 10:50 src`


    `drwxr-xr-x  15 buhion  staff   480 Mar 16 10:55 target`

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it

Comment: I can indeed reproduce the error when using the docker daemon from Minishift. However when using the local docker daemon everything works just fine, so I would say this is not a Quarkus problem, so much as an unsupported use case

Answer (score 3):

The related [Issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1610) has been resolved at Quarkus github and remote container support is here.

Quoting the resolution comment:

> Building native images using a remote docker daemon has been
> implemented and merged for Quarkus 1.13 (PR #14635). Just use the flag
> `-Dquarkus.native.remote-container-build=true` instead of
> `-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true`.

So if you using minishift or minikube just use the
new option while building.

Answer (score 1):

The `-Dnative-image.docker-build=true` feature of Quarkus will only work with the *local* docker daemon.

In your case you are using the Docker daemon from Minishift and the build files because the build artifacts are not present in the Minishift VM.

*UPDATE*

There is now a Quarkus [issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1610) that tracks this.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. 
Aside from local docker, I've tested that this also works with minikube docker

Comment: @yjsa if your goal is just to build a Native Quarkus app on Minishift (OpenShift), then you may be interested in the S2I support coming up in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/1358?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to combine the process of creating the application image and the actual compilation into one Dockerfile.

Your Dockerfile should contain 3 stages

- build the java app
- build the native image
- build the final Docker image

First stage is for the fast fail if app has compilation issues ++ to build the jar file

Second stage is to produce native image from the jar + libs via native-image command or you can use "mvn -Pnative verify" if you are using an image which contains both maven and graalvm.

Third stage is to build the final Docker image based on the compiled native image and minimal base image such as alpine or fedora-minimal

An example of building the app ++ building the native image ++ building the final Docker image - https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/master/getting-started-knative/Dockerfile